# passing an image picked from a file from current page to the navigated page on UWP 10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm working with windows universal apps 10 (c#/xaml) and I made a "NavigationContext" class to pass data from a page to another, but I am not sure how to pass an image (picked from a file) to an other page .

```
private async void tt3_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
              {  openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
                openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
                StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
                if (file != null)
                {var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                    var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                    img.Source = bitmapImage;
                    var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream); }}
```

Click event to navigate to the next page and passing data

```
private void fw_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationContext nav = new NavigationContext()
            {
                 Latitude = lat.Text;
                //code to pass image
            };
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Description), nav);}
```

And what should I put on the navigationcontext class?

```
class NavigationContext
    {
        public String Latitude { get; set; }
        // image attributes
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest thing would be to pass the StorageFile object in your context and do the image processing on the destination page. Or, use FileIO.ReadAsync to pull out the data from the file, and pass that. That way you can reuse it however you wish.

Comment: the file can be removed, moved after picked .. so any idea how to serialize the image in the local file of the app and how to locate it and deserialize it

Comment: If you want to save it within the app's storage so you can access it anytime, just call file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.LocalFolder). If you need to store the filename somewhere, drop it into settings - ApplicationData.LocalSettings.Values["FileName"] = file.Name